# New ionic page returns error "device ready fired after..."

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

what can i do after add a new page?
i add a "TestPage" and modified the code as follows:

in app.component.ts:

```
import { TestPage } from '../pages/TestPage/TestPagePage';
```

and:

```
this.pages = [

{ title: 'Page One', component: Page1 },

  { title: 'Page Two', component: Page2 },

  { title: 'Test Page', component: TestPage }

];
```

in app.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import { TestPage } from '../pages/TestPage/TestPagePage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2,
    TestPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2,
    TestPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but, return an error!!

"device ready fired after 935ms"
main.js

what should I do? what other code should i add?

thanks

**********SOLUTION!!!***********

Visual Studio generate incorrect code!! when i add a new ionic page (page3), visual studio, add this code at page3.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/*
  Generated class for the page3 page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
    selector: 'page-page3',
    templateUrl: 'page3.html'
})
export class page3page {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) { }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad page3Page');
    }

}
```

but, this code work well (not the code above):

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-page3',
    templateUrl: 'page3.html'
})
export class Page3 {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }

    onLink(url: string) {
        window.open(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: "device ready fired after 935ms" is not an error. Can you be more descriptive about your error, or possibly add a screenshot of it?

Comment: on browser debug, console, there are several errors. the first is on "main.js": "throw new Error("Cannot find module \"../pages/TestPage/TestPagePage\"");"

Comment: How did you create that page? Try to always use the Ionic CLI generate command to make new pages - https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/.  Then make sure your import statement points to the correct path to that page.  One or both of those things are wrong.

Comment: visual studio generate incorrect code!! i generate a new page...look the solution above